Blender using my GPU in the viewport but not while rendering
I am using blender 4.3 but the problem existed in older versions aswell. I have a RTX 4060, I tried selecting CUDA and OptiX with both GPU and CPU and updated my driver. The problem is while beeing in the viewport in rendered mode the task manager shows GPU 100% and it's way faster than rendering. But if I render the animation, then task manager shows CPU 100% and GPU almmost nothing. I looked at other posts here but I couldn't find any solution to the problem. I want it to use the GPU for rendering aswell. I don't even understand why it's using GPU only in the viewport.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Not all parts of rendering use the GPU, there are some preliminary processes that use the CPU

Task Manager may report GPU usage incorrectly. Also note that you can track activity of different aspects of GPU load:

Consider using some other software to check GPU load if you care about it.
There are also separate settings for render and viewport render to trade quality for speed when previewing rendering in the viewport and you may have lower resolution in the viewport so it's entirely plausible that viewport rendering is faster for you.
